# Android - Accessibility "Talkback" make system read image word aloud; add "image" suffix to image

Tags: android, accessibility, uiaccessibility, talkback

I have the following (quite standard) view. `ImageView` with `android:contentDescription` is the important part. My question concerns only **Accessibility features**.

ImageView is the default: `android.widget.ImageView`

`android:contentDescription` is set to "My cool dog" and the system reads (speaks) via **Android Talkback** exactly the same: "My cool dog".

I want it to read: "My cool dog **image**". How can I add the suffix "image" to the talkback's message?

Ideally I'd like to have something similar to `context.getString(android.R.string.accessibility_button)` which would localised to specific languages.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <data></data>

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/welcome_image"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:contentDescription="@{viewModel.imageAccessebilityDescription}"
            app:imageRes="..." />
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 2):

A lot of contextual information is communicated to users through 'beeps', 'boops' etc. You might not have noticed it. That is why you don't hear that it is an image.

You should never add 'image' to the end of a description. You have to bear in mind that there are `BrailleBack` users who do not want this extra information and it would actually reduce accessibility for those users (imagine there are several images one after the other, they would read **'image, my cool dog, image, image, another cool dog, image'**. That would get confusing, did they miss an image, how many images were there etc.).

Now if you want to make it more clear an acceptable `contentDescription` would be **'A picture of my cool dog'** vs **'my cool dog, image'** as at least that makes sense to all users.

Although not ideal you can use this to your advantage in that you can describe the style of the image with terms such as **'an illustration of...', 'a painting of...', 'a drawing of...', 'a photograph of...'** etc. At least that way you are not adding completely unneeded information, even if in reality `TalkBack` should do better here.

I know this makes it more difficult to automate for `i18n` etc. but this will provide a much better experience and be WCAG compliant. Instead I would just switch out the entire `contentDescription` for each language.

Comment: OK, thanks for the detailed info. That's a lot of work for the internationalisation team but I'll definitely let them know :)

Comment: Hopefully you can streamline that side of the process, for most languages the phrases I suggested will translate across in a grammatically correct way / you can find a process for masculine / feminine etc. It is just 'moving the problem' to your translation process, rather than trying to deal with it in the front end. Best thing is, it is a legitimate 'pass the buck' so not your problem (not often that happens :-) )